# Selecting the right URL using FileReference (AS3) to download a file

Tags: php, actionscript-3, url, download, filereference

I’m going crazy in vane trying to download files from my flash website to someone else’s hard drive. I red one or two similar challenges at this forum but they are much more complicate than mine. The files are .mp3 and I don’t want to convert them to .zip. So I used FileReference. It seemed to work OK. But the big trouble is the URL I have to choose and write in the code. My enemy is the incessant dilemma to set:

```
A)   (http://mysite.net/myfolder/myfile.mp3);

or B)   (http://www.mysite.net/myfolder/myfile.mp3);
```

Because if the site’s visitor doesn’t realize that his URL contains (or not) the right characters ([triple "W"] or http://[triple "W"]), the file, simply, won’t download. I don’t know how to “fusion” or link both prefixes dynamically to get a infallible good result… I could set two buttons, but that is extremely unusual… (By the way, I had exactly the same problem with the Contact Parse that links php to flash for mailing). Please give me a hand! Thank you in advance! The code is:

```
var myfileReference:FileReference = new FileReference();
var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.mysite.net/myfolder/myfile.mp3");
function downloadFile (event:MouseEvent):void {
    myfileReference.download(myRequest);
}
download_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, downloadFile);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to this problem in the code of the class that I let down here. You just need to add (in the .fla) a button for each downloading file, two identical bars (mc) to indicate the progress ("mc_progress" and "mc_loaded") and a text field to know the action is done (txt_prog.text). That's it. You may find the whole thing here: http://dev.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-download-files-through-swfs-using-filereference--active-9068

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.net.FileReference;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class fileref extends Sprite
    {
        //Donload Buttons
        public var btn_img_download : MovieClip,
                   btn_txt_download : MovieClip,
                   btn_mp3_download : MovieClip,
                   mc_loaded        : MovieClip;

        //Progress Bar
        public var mc_progress : MovieClip,
                   txt_prog    : TextField;

        //Download links Array
        private var Arr_Links  : Array;

        //Default Parent Path for Downloads 
        private var defaultPath : String = "files/";

        //Filen Name
        private var urlName : String;

        //instance of FileReference() Class
        private var fr : FileReference;

        //url of the requested files
        private var req : URLRequest;

        public function fileref() : void
        {
            //Set buttonModes of the download buttons
            btn_img_download.buttonMode = btn_txt_download.buttonMode = btn_mp3_download.buttonMode = true;

            //Set width of the mc_loaded progress bar to 0
            mc_loaded.scaleX = 0;

            //Create list of files to be downloaded
            Arr_Links = ["myimage.jpg","myaudio.mp3","mytext.rtf"];

            req = new URLRequest();
            fr = new FileReference();

            //Download buttons Event Listeners
            btn_img_download.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK,downloadFile );
            btn_mp3_download.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK,downloadFile );
            btn_txt_download.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK,downloadFile );

            fr.addEventListener( ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,progressHandler );
            fr.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE,completeHandler );

        }

        private function downloadFile( e : MouseEvent ) : void
        {
            //set the download path to the urlName variable according to clicked Download Button
            switch (e.target.name)
            {
                case "btn_img_download":
                urlName = Arr_Links[0];
                break;

                case "btn_mp3_download":
                urlName = Arr_Links[1];
                break;

                case "btn_txt_download":
                urlName = Arr_Links[2];
                break;
            }

            //change text message "progress" to "downloading..." at txt_prog
            txt_prog.text = "downloading...";

            //Assign url to the req
            req.url = defaultPath + urlName;

            //Downlaod requested file
            fr.download( req );         
        }

        private function progressHandler( event : ProgressEvent ) : void
        {           
            mc_loaded.scaleX = (event.bytesLoaded / event.bytesTotal) ;
        }

        private function completeHandler( event : Event ) : void
        {
            //reset progress bar after download is finished
            mc_loaded.scaleX = 0;
            txt_prog.text = "download finished";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LoaderInfo class.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html

Its instance is assigned to each staged DisplayObject. It contains loaderUrl property, which might help you to decide, which URL to use.

Comment: Thanks, Petr! Unfortunately I got a little lost in that Class. I think it’s good to download images (jpg, png, etc.) from stage, but I still can’t handle mp3 (or pdf) files… Instead of this I was considering, actually, the possibility to “generate” a zip file with one or two different files at the very moment of the “downloading click” (let’s say one mp3 + one pdf), but I can’t do it without duplicating the space in my project, I mean: without adding the .zip weight plus the mp3’s I use also as sounds (that’s’ why I didn’t set those zip files before).

Comment: I see. Could you specify where are you lost with LoaderInfo class? loaderURL contains url from which was swf downloaded. Thus you should be able to get the host part of url. And then you should be able to build appropriate download url.